# Load time of a page in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I understand that the primary use of Jmeter is not finding the load time of a page. However, I'd like to know if there's any tool for the below scenario to calculate the approximate load time of a page (barring the rendering time):

- Calculate the response time of various web requests for a particular page P1 using JMeter
- Record and save the web request pattern of the page P1 in the desired browser
- A tool replaces every web request in the pattern with the response time recorded in Step 1 and based on the timeline slice in Step 2, gives us the load time of the given page P1

Hope I'm making sense

Answer (score 1):

Actually the answer lives at [JMeter Home Page](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

> JMeter is not a browser. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever viewed at a time)

You don't need to do anything as JMeter doesn't actually render page. You may want to perform some [tweaks to make it behave more like a real browser](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1743654-how-to-make-jmeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser), especially [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) matters.

In regards to saving browser traffic - for [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/) and derivatives you can do it right from Developer Tools by right-clicking a request in Network tab

[image: Chromium Record Traffic]

Comment: thanks for answering. I guess I was not clear with my question. After running the performance test using jmeter, how can I calculate the approximate load time of a page? (I fully understand that Jmeter does not render webpages). Is there a tool that can substitute the web requests recorded & saved in a browser with the requests (with the time) that were obtained using Jmeter